# Joomla URL-Rewrite

Tags: joomla, iis-7, url-rewriting, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I've got a little strange behavior from a joomla website (2.5) with the url rewriting.

Here is my situation:

Two identical Websites. One runs with joomla 1.5, the other with joomla 2.5. Both on a IIS 7. There is a external plugin (build by own) which posts a list of article-links on both joomla. Some kind of a "latest news" module on the homepage.
This plugin posts link with a url like this:
**index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2518&Itemid=97&lang=de**

This link is working, if the URL-rewrite is switched off in joomla back-end. Now when I switch on the url-rewriting. The links look like these:

**Joomla 1.5**
http://example.com/de/category/news/2518.html (link does work!)

**Joomla 2.5**
http://example.com/de/category/news.html?id=2518 (link does not work! 404)

It seems there is a difference between those joomla versions. Can anyone give me a hint to solve this problem with joomla 2.5? thank you very much.

Comment: Have you seen this link: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/install-joomla-on-iis

Comment: Thank you, I've already tried. The URL-rewriting of these joomlas are working except on the plug-in explain above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. Now I build my links in the plugin with [JRoute](http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component):

```
$link = JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=$id&catid=$catid:$catalias&Itemid=$itemid");
```